# When are default route values used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm confused about default routing values.  Here's the default route in an MVC app:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I don't understand why it specifies a default value for, say, {controller}, because it seems to me that this route won't ever be used unless the user requests a url like `/xyz/dosomething/123`, and in that case the controller is simply `xyz`, and we don't need the default value.

So, with a route like this, when would the default controller and action values ever be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be used if you don't specify them in the url : `http://whatever.com` will be treated as `http://whatever.com/Home/Index`.

Comment: I thought that a route like {controller}/{action}/{id} had to match /something/something/something.  But you're saying that if you specify defaults, it can match /something/something or just /something or even just /.  If you omit the defaults, does it have to match the exact pattern?

Comment: Indeed, submitting `http://whatever.com/Other` will search for an `Index` action in `OtherController`. But the pattern must be matched, as you can't write the action name before the controller name for example, unless you change/add routes.

Comment: Suppose the pattern is `{controller}/{action}`.  Is it correct to say that the route will match `/abc/xyz` AND `/abc` IF a default action is specified, but ONLY `/abc/xyz` (the full route) if no default action is specified?

Comment: It is correct, this is how it works. Also, if you're action has parameters that are not specified (like `id` in the default route), you'll have to add them to the url

Comment: Okay, I understand much better now.  Thanks so much for your help.  Last question: in the case of `id`, suppose you specify a default, but the default value is `UrlParameter.Optional`?  Then will it match `/abc/xyz` AND `/abc/xyz/123` or only `/abc/xyz`?

Comment: `UrlParameter.Optional` means that it will match `/abc/xyz` AND `/abc/xyz/123`, however your `id` parameter must be nullable, otherwise a value is mandatory. Having it specified in your route saves your from writing `/abc/xyz?id=123`

Answer (score 2):

The default controller and action will be used when the page `/` is requested, i.e. when someone browses to just your domain address, e.g. `http://www.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Can you see my question/comment to @Réda Mattar?  I'm still confused about how this works.